# Small implementation of a singly-linked list in C89

Tags: beginner, c, linked-list

I'm very new to C and have extensive experience with C# and very little with C++, but basically none with C.

I wrote a small program that declares a singly-linked list struct, a few methods operating on the list, and then uses it from the main method. Even though I've read about it a lot, this is only my second/third program I've written in C, so please beware.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct linked_list_node linked_list_node; // forward declare linked_list_node and add it to the struct/global namespaces

struct linked_list_node
{
    linked_list_node* next;
    int32_t item;
};

typedef struct
{
    linked_list_node* head;
    size_t size;
} linked_list;

void init_list(linked_list* list) { /* Nothing to do here */ }

void add_last(linked_list* list, int32_t item)
{
    assert(list != NULL);

    if (list->head == NULL)
    {
        // No elements in the list yet.
        list->head = malloc(sizeof(linked_list_node));
        list->head->next = NULL;
        list->head->item = item;
    }
    else
    {
        // At least 1 element in the list.
        assert(list->size > 0);

        // Walk the list until we find the last node.
        linked_list_node* node = list->head;
        while (node->next != NULL)
        {
            node = node->next;
        }

        // Allocate a new last node
        linked_list_node* next = malloc(sizeof(linked_list_node)); // note: no typecast from void* here
        node->next = next;
        next->next = NULL; // need to explicitly do this since malloc's memory is uninitialized
        next->item = item;
    }

    list->size++;
}

typedef void action(int32_t);

void foreach_list(linked_list* list, action* act)
{
    assert(list != NULL && act != NULL);

    linked_list_node* node;
    for (node = list->head;
        node != NULL;
        node = node->next)
    {
        act(node->item);
    }
}

// Cleans up all of the memory used up by the list's
// nodes. DOES NOT FREE THE LIST ITSELF.
void cleanup_list(linked_list* list)
{
    assert(list != NULL);

    list->size = 0;

    // Walk the list, freeing nodes as we go.
    linked_list_node* node, *next;
    for (node = list->head;
        node != NULL;
        node = next)
    {
        next = node->next;
        free(node);
    }
}

void print_int32(int32_t to_print)
{
    printf("Found %"PRIi32"!\n", to_print); // format specifier for int32_t
}

int main(void)
{
    linked_list list;
    memset(&list, 0, sizeof(list));
    init_list(&list);

    add_last(&list, 3);
    add_last(&list, 4);
    add_last(&list, 5);

    foreach_list(&list, print_int32);
    printf("Size: %"PRIu64"\n", (uint64_t)list.size); // do not use %zu since this is targeting C89

    cleanup_list(&list);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled this under MinGW with C89.

Here is the type of feedback I'm looking for:

- Did I introduce and potential sources of UB? For example, is there a flaw in my logic where a NULL pointer can be dereferenced and go undetected by asserts?
- Is my memory management logic correct? Did I accidentally `malloc` something that never got cleared, or did I `free` anything twice in `cleanup_list`? Is there a way to make all of the logic less error-prone?
- Did I rely on any features specific to GCC to get this to work? For example, will this program also work with other compilers under C89?
- Any way I could clean up the code and make it more neat/concise? (I am aware that I should probably have put the list definition/methods into separate header/source files than `main`.)

Answer (score 3):

- **`init_list`**

  should really initialize the list. Otherwise you are forcing the caller to make an non-obvious `memset`.

  ```
  void init_list(linked_list * list) {
      list->head = 0;
      list->size = 0;
  }
  ```

  is much more clean.
- **`add_last`**

  is not a particularly good name. Traditionally this operation is called `append` or `push_back`.

  The function can be streamlined. First, assert your invariant fully (that is either `head == 0 and size == 0` or `head != 0 and size > 0`) and immediately.

  Second, once the invariant is deemed correct, allocate the node (you need to do it anyway). It is a good idea to delegate node allocation to a function.

  Finally, find the tail (it is also a good candidate to factor out into a function), and attach the node. For example,

  ```
  void append (linked_list * list, int32_t item)
  {
      assert(list_is_good(list));
      linked_list_node * node = create_list_node(item);
      linked_list_node * tail = find_list_tail(list);
      if (tail == NULL) {
          list->head = node;
      } else {
          tail->next = node;
      }
      list->size += 1;
  }
  ```
- **malloc may fail**

  Test the results of `malloc`. There is not much you can do once it fails, but it is good form anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> Did I introduce and potential sources of UB?

A1. Lack of check that `malloc()` worked.

```
list->head = malloc(sizeof(linked_list_node));
if (list->head == NULL) We_Are_Outta_Here();
list->head->next = ... // Potential UB.
```

> Is my memory management logic correct?

B1. Rather than have `init_list()` initialize the head pointer, the calling code does a `memset()` to clear the `list`.  It makes more sense and is more understandable to have `init_list()` do that clearing.

```
linked_list list;
// Move memset / initialization to `init_list()`
// memset(&list, 0, sizeof(list));
init_list(&list);
```

B2. Although `cleanup_list()` is OK, consider adding a scrub.  By zeroing free'd resources, code that inadvertently accesses free'd data tends to fail quicker.  Sooner bad code fails, easier it is to ID and fix.

```
memset(node, 0, sizeof *node); // add to enhance debugging.
free(node);
```

> Did I accidentally malloc something ..  Is there a way to make all of the logic less error-prone?

C1. `free(NULL)` is OK code and like-wise allowing `cleanup_list()` to free again a link list is good.  Just clear the head node to an initial state.  Detail:  `cleanup_list()` should be able to be followed by a another `init_list()`.

```
memset(list, 0, sizeof *list); // add to cleanup_list()
```

C2.  Allocate to the size of the reference type.  Less error prone.  No need to code the matching type.

```
// list->head = malloc(sizeof(linked_list_node))
list->head = malloc(sizeof *(list->head))
```

C3. `foreach_list()` lacks a method for the called `action` to abort the loop.  Further, make more useful to also pass a *state* variable into `act()`

```
{
    // Allow `act()` to quit early 
    if(act(state, node->item)) return 1;
}
```

> Did I rely on any features specific to GCC to get this to work? For example will this program also work with other compilers under C89?

D1. `printf("Size: %"PRIu64"\n", (uint64_t)list.size); // do not use %zu since this is targeting C89` is odd.  Both `uint64_t` and `"%zu"` are C99 features and `uint64_t` is an *optional* type even in C99,C11.  The simple and portable alternative to print types lacking a known matching specifier is to cast to a wide supported type.

```
printf("Size: %lu\n", (unsigned long) list.size);
// or if desperate for a wide type
printf("Size: %.0f\n", 1.0 * list.size);
```

D2.  `int32_t` is an optional type in C99,C11.  It does not exist in C89.  Consider `long`.

D3. `#include <inttypes.h>` is not C89.

> Any way I could clean up the code and make it more neat/concise?

E1. Segment into .h and .c files.